# Calculate the number of samples with alterations each gene listed in a vector

Tags: r

I'm an R newby and wondering if people could offer me a little bit of advice as to how I can process some data I have.

I have a data frame containing a list of samples with observed changes in genes (example below)

```
Dataframe1:
Sample  Gene  Alteration
1       A     -1
1       B     -1
1       C     -1
1       D      1
2       B      1
2       E     -1 ...
```

I also have a data frame containing a list of genes that I am interested in (example below)

```
Dataframe2:
Gene
B
D
E
```

I want to calculate how many samples have a -1 alteration for each gene in dataframe2, with an ideal output looking something like:

```
Dataframe3:
Gene   Alteration   Sum
B      -1            23
D      -1            2
E      -1            18
```

I'm really stuck as to where to start, I've found a lot of information on sum etc but I can't work out how to feed two data frames together and utilise sum.

Any advice or just functions that I could try would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function ddply from the package plyr.

```
library(plyr)
Dataframe3 <- ddply(Dataframe1, c('Gene', 'Alteration'), summarise, Sum = length(Alteration))
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Select the genes of interest from dataframe1:

```
set.seed(11)
dataframe1 = data.frame(Sample = rep(c(1,2), each = 5),
                      Gene = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D","E"),2),
                      Alteration = sample(c(-1, 1), 10, prob = c(0.7, 0.3), replace = TRUE))
dataframe2 <- data.frame(Gene = c("B", "D", "E"))

# Select the genes of interest
dataframe1 <- dataframe1[dataframe1$Gene %in% dataframe2$Gene, ]
```

Step 2: Calculate the sum of -1's

We can use the `dplyr` library to compute the sum per group:

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe1 %>%
    group_by(Gene) %>%
    summarise(Sum = sum(Alteration == -1))
```

Note that when we have a boolean vector (vector containing TRUE's and FALSE's) the sum of this vector gives the number of TRUE's.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Or with `dplyr`, just try

```
dft2 %>% 
  inner_join(dft1) %>%
  group_by(Gene, Alteration) %>%
  summarise( cnt = n()) %>%
  filter(Alteration == -1)
```

where `dft1` is the first dataframe and `dft2` is the second dataframe

In case `dft2` has entries not found in `dft1`  and you want to show the null, change the `inner_join` to `left_join`